# php Form Validation on a textarea

Tags: php, regex, validation, newline

I recently switched a input form from a text to a textarea so that I could have multiple lines of text.
The form is working fine except when I go to validate. If it is one line, there is no problem but when I enter text that wraps to the second line, i get an error from my form validator (only letters and numbers are allowed) here is my code:

```
private function validate_alnum($var, $min=0, $max=0, $required=false, $err="") {
   if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0) {
          return true;
 }
 if(isset($this->source[$var])){
   if(strlen($this->source[$var]) < $min) {
     $this->errors[$var] = $err . ' is too short. It has to be at least '.$min. ' character(s)';
   } elseif(strlen($this->source[$var]) > $max) {
      $this->errors[$var] = $err . " is too long. It can't be more than ".$max. " characters";
    } elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -.:,]*$/", $this->source[$var])) {
$this->errors[$var] = $err . ' is invalid.  Only letters and numbers are allowed';
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your function takes too many parameters meaning it's doing to much. Kindly consider assigning functionality to other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't allow new lines. Try:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9\s.:,]*$
```

also `-` should be the first or last character if you want it to be literal, otherwise it makes a range.

The `\s` here will allow for single spaces, new lines, and tabs. ( [Additional reading](https://books.google.com/books?id=587w6j5vPIQC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=s+metacharacter&source=bl&ots=0sro_GEnc5&sig=kDjDZS38GecyDAhBwwzjtRkXaSM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHkfD7-MfUAhUFXD4KHYOdB6cQ6AEIRDAF#v=onepage&q=s%20metacharacter&f=false) on the `\s`)

If you change the quantifier to `+` you can be sure there is more than 1 character in the string, which would take out your default `$min` requirement (the error message would be less specific though).

Comment: Just a note, here is the same pattern condensed: `/^[-a-z\d\s.:,]*$/i`

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply and information. Interesting mickmackusa

Comment: To continue, mickmackusa's regex /^[-a-z\d\s.:,]*$/i solved the issue but i still got the same validation error with ^[-a-zA-Z0-9\s.:,]*$     Not sure why?

Comment: @cbspaulding mickmackusa and my regex will function the same.. What does `var_dump($this->source[$var])` return?

Comment: this is var_dump:   string(4) "Book" string(116) "Inventive Weaving on a Little Loom: Discover the Full Potential of the Rigid-Heddle Loom, for Beginners and Beyond" string(4) "1211" string(4) "2015" string(0) "" string(5) "19.00" NULL string(10) "05/01/2017" string(4) "0.00"           The title of the book is what is generates the error with your regex but no error with mickmackusa.

Comment: The regex provided by @mickmackusa and I are the same, except he is using the `i` modifier rather than specifying the lowercase ascii range. Can you provided an example of where my regex fails and mickmack's works? Here's a demo of them performing the same https://3v4l.org/A7TIp vs. https://3v4l.org/OQEYN